# Crm 2011 with no javascript customizations gives onload errors

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

we are getting the following error in almost all create or edit entity forms. the systems is not customized at all and it works perfectly:

There was an error in the fields customized event. 
field:window 
event:onload 
error:**object doesn't support this property or method**

after debugging the error I found out that it is happening in FormScript.js.aspx page in the following code block:

```
var eContext=Mscrm.FormUtility.constructExecutionObject(eventObj,0,null,null);
eContext=Mscrm.FormUtility.constructExecutionObject(eventObj,0,null,eContext)
Mscrm.Form_onload();
```

Mscrm.Form_onload() is what causing the error to happen.
do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Does this occur after an update from CRM4? Or is it a fresh installation?

Comment: it is a fresh install but we used the deployment manager’s import organisation process to upgrade our existing Version 4 organisation. the old crm 4 was not customized in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a server side problem. I don't know exactly why it happens. we also tried to do an installation repair but that didn't solve it. Finally, we installed a fresh CRM 2011 copy on a new server, imported the database and ran Data migration manager. and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely positive there is no script attached to run on load of any of the entities that are having issues? That particular function should just run any custom script you have on the entity, so I don't see any other cause.

Comment: absolutely sure... it also happens for system dialogs such as "Customize this system".

Comment: @ziwar In this case I would open a call with the Microsoft Support

Answer (score 0):

Odd, there is certainly some garbage in there somewhere

```
function crmForm_window_onload_handler(eventObj,eventArgs){
  try{
    var eContext=Mscrm.FormUtility.constructExecutionObject(eventObj,0,null,null);
    eContext=Mscrm.FormUtility.constructExecutionObject(eventObj,0,null,eContext)
    loadInsideView();
    eContext=Mscrm.FormUtility.constructExecutionObject(eventObj,1,null,eContext)
    CEI.Initialize();
  } catch(e) {
    displayError('window', 'onload', e.description);
  }
}
```

Here is one from our system on the account form.  I have no idea how this could have happened, but I would check the events for the page (not just the onload).  I would also try adding a JavaScript web resource with a generic event to the onload to see if by toggling it on, the system might clean itself up.  You may have to call Microsoft or find the issue in your 4.0 and fix it to do another re-install.  I feel for you on this one!